# How to Sum text and number sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

input:

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT SUM(CAST("Item Total" as FLOAT)) FROM price')
res_sum = cursor.fetchone()
print(res_sum)
```

output:

```
(0.0,)
```

example:
$47.99 + $47.99 + $47.99 + $47.99

Comment: You can't sum TEXT. Store numeric values in the table, not strings.

Comment: this structure comes from .csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SELECT SUM(CAST(substr("item total",2) AS FLOAT)) FROM price;`

However, it would be better to store the values without the currency character. You could always prepend the value when extracting if so desired.

e.g. `SELECT '$'||SUM(CAST(substr("item total",2) AS FLOAT)) FROM price;` would output $191.96 as opposed to just 191.96.